# Enumerate files and directoris with command 'ls'

Tags: bash

Run Command `ls` on Current Directory and get the output:

```
    $ ls
    Applications Documents    Library      Music        Public
    Desktop      Downloads    Movies       Pictures
```

I'd like to enumerate them like:

```
1. Applications
2. Desktop
3. Documents
4. Downloads
5. Library
6. Movies
7. Music
8. Pictures
9. Public
```

This could be achieved using `less` in an intermediate way

```
ls | less -N
```

How to enumerate them in a straigtforward way?

Comment: Same as the dupe, but the input is from a command output rather than a file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nl` on the command line:

```
ls | nl
```